# ASP classic - how do I join an array of strings / join / implode do not work

Tags: join, asp-classic, request.form

```
Dim stringIdCollection
    stringIdCollection = Join( Request.Form( "id" ), "', '" ) )    
Dim whereStatement
    whereStatement = "WHERE id IN ('" & stringIdCollection & "');"
```

I get this error:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation  error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement
>
> /includes/Process.asp, line 49  stringIdCollection = Join(
>   Request.Form( "id" ), "', '" ) )
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------^

Is it even possible to use Join on a Request.Form?

I would like the output to be:

> "WHERE id IN ('122', '344', '599')"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `join` function expects an array as the first parameter. In Classic ASP (VBScript) the data in `Request.Form` is always string, so impossible to have an actual array in it, you have to build the array yourself :

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array(Request.Form("id"), Request.Form("id2"), Request.Form("id3"))

Dim stringIdCollection
stringIdCollection = Join( myArray , "', '" ) )
```

Also notice that in Classic ASP, if you submit multiple form fields with the same names (i.e. `id`), they will get in `Request.Form` already separated by a commas.

Contrary to what can be done in PHP, naming multiple form fields with square brackets [] appended at the end, ASP will not convert it as an array in Request.Form.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an extra parentheses on the second line that should be deleted:

```
    stringIdCollection = Join( Request.Form( "id" ), "', '" )
```

---

EDIT: The documentation for [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a little bit misleading. The value returned by `Request.Form("item")` isn't really an array, but an array-like object. You can iterate through those values by using the `Count` property and build your string as you iterate:

```
Dim stringIdCollection, i

For i = 1 To Request.Form("id").Count
    If Len(stringIdCollection) <> 0 Then
        stringIdCollection = stringIdCollection & ","
    End If
    stringIdCollection = stringIdCollection & "'" & Request.Form("id")(i) & "'"
Next
```

Comment: Well, that certainly was the problem... alas, it becomes apparent that MaxiWheat has a point "Type mismatch: 'Join' "

Comment: @JamesT, see my edit. Request.Form doesn't really return an array or a string, but an array-like object.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info