# How to avoid first instance of data while string concatenation

Tags: vbscript

I am concatenation hlinks obtained from word do

```
data = data & "," & Vbcr & hlnk.Address & ":" & hlnk.TextToDisplay
```

Here ',' is separator.

Now I get every time data starting with ',' (obviously)

I then use

```
data = Right(data,Len(data)-1)
```

But I doubted my method of string concatenation.
Am I using Right method of string concatenation in first place?

I have seen [ASP classic - how do I join an array of strings / join / implode do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113216/asp-classic-how-do-i-join-an-array-of-strings-join-implode-do-not-work) but I don't think that is my case. I am not joining array but creating one.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: ma I doing string concatenation rightly in first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP classic - how do I join an array of strings / join / implode do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113216/asp-classic-how-do-i-join-an-array-of-strings-join-implode-do-not-work) ... in the sense of: should have answers that fit this problem.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject I would say what you are doing is fine.

Comment: Thanks.  @Filburt: I don't understand how that's duplicate question. I will try to understand and delete if that's the same.

Comment: You don't have to be using an Array at first, just do `data = Join(Array(data, vbCr & hlnk.Address & ":" & hlnk.TextToDisplay), ",")` *(obviously depends how you iterate through the remaining results)*.

Comment: Ignore the question, look [at the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15115615/692942).

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject not an 100% exact duplicate ... that's why I added *"...in the sense of: should have answers that fit this problem"*

Comment: Thanks. Now I understood. Now as it has answers I can not delete.

Comment: Already up voted. I was busy trying but stuck for other problem. I hate VBscript and Powershell is banned. Can't install any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way to avoid leading (or trailing) list separators is to collect the items you want to concatenate in an array, then join that array. That's probably why [@Filburt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020256/how-to-avoid-first-instance-of-data-while-string-concatenation#comment61591764_37020256) considered your question a (borderline) duplicate. If you don't know the number of items beforehand you'd dynamically resize the array:

```
ReDim a(-1)
For Each hlnk In ...
  ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a)+1)
  a(UBound(a)) = hlnk.Address & ":" & hlnk.TextToDisplay
Next
```

Once the array is filled you simply join the elements:

```
data = Join(a, "," & vbCr)
```

Otherwise you need to either handle the first (or last) element differently from the rest:

```
If IsEmpty(data) Then
  data = hlnk.Address & ":" & hlnk.TextToDisplay
Else
  data = data & "," & vbCr & hlnk.Address & ":" & hlnk.TextToDisplay
End If
```

or remove the leading (trailing) separator after you finished constructing the string:

```
data = Mid(data, 3)
```